# Can anyone explain the reason behind the fact given below for this implentation of quicksort on singly linked list? why the execution time varies?

Tags: sorting, time-complexity, quicksort, execution-time

in the given below code execution time decreases by rougly 80 or 90 times or more specially in case when we have redundant values in the linked list when we use (start.data <= pivot) instead of (start.data < pivot) in the partition function used by the sort function internally.

given below is the sequence of values in the linked list :
4  4  3  3  3  4  1  1  2  3  4  5  1  1  2  3  4  5  1  1  2  3  4  5  4  4  3  3  3  4  1  1  2  3  4  5  1  1  2  3  4  5  1  1  2  3  4  5  4  4  3  3

when we use (start.data <= pivot) in the partition function execution time is rougly about 12-15 milliseconds

when we use (start.data < pivot) in the partition function execution time is rougly about 700 milliseconds or more.

can anyone help me on this?

```
public class Sheet_1 {
    static class Node {
        int data;
        Node next;

        Node(int d) {
            this.data = d;
            this.next = null;
        }
    }

    Node head;

    void addNode(int data) {
        if (head == null) {
            head = new Node(data);
            return;
        }
        Node curr = head;
        while (curr.next != null) {
            curr = curr.next;
        }
        Node newNode = new Node(data);
        curr.next = newNode;
    }

    void printList(Node n) {
        Node curr = n;
        while (curr != null) {
            System.out.print(curr.data + "  ");
            curr = curr.next;
        }
    }

    Node partition(Node start, Node end) {
        if (start == null || start == end || start == end.next)
            return start;
        Node pivot_prev = start;
        Node curr = start;
        int pivot = end.data;

        while (start != end) {
            if (start.data <= pivot) {
                pivot_prev = curr;
                int temp = start.data;
                start.data = curr.data;
                curr.data = temp;
                curr = curr.next;
            }
            start = start.next;
        }
        int temp = curr.data;
        curr.data = pivot;
        end.data = temp;

        return pivot_prev;
    }

    void sort(Node start, Node end) {
        if (start == null || start == end || start == end.next)
            return;
        Node pivot_prev = partition(start, end);

        sort(start, pivot_prev);

        if (pivot_prev != null && pivot_prev == start)
            sort(pivot_prev.next, end);

        if (pivot_prev != null && pivot_prev.next != null)
            sort(pivot_prev.next.next, end);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Sheet_1 list = new Sheet_1();
        list.addNode(4);
        list.addNode(4);
        list.addNode(3);
        list.addNode(3);
        list.addNode(3);
        list.addNode(4);
        list.addNode(1);
        list.addNode(1);
        list.addNode(2);
        list.addNode(3);
        list.addNode(4);
        list.addNode(5);
        list.addNode(1);
        list.addNode(1);
        list.addNode(2);
        list.addNode(3);
        list.addNode(4);
        list.addNode(5);
        list.addNode(1);
        list.addNode(1);
        list.addNode(2);
        list.addNode(3);
        list.addNode(4);
        list.addNode(5);
        list.addNode(4);
        list.addNode(4);
        list.addNode(3);
        list.addNode(3);
        list.addNode(3);
        list.addNode(4);
        list.addNode(1);
        list.addNode(1);
        list.addNode(2);
        list.addNode(3);
        list.addNode(4);
        list.addNode(5);
        list.addNode(1);
        list.addNode(1);
        list.addNode(2);
        list.addNode(3);
        list.addNode(4);
        list.addNode(5);
        list.addNode(1);
        list.addNode(1);
        list.addNode(2);
        list.addNode(3);
        list.addNode(4);
        list.addNode(5);
        list.addNode(4);
        list.addNode(4);
        list.addNode(3);
        list.addNode(3);
        list.addNode(3);
        list.addNode(4);
        list.addNode(1);
        list.addNode(1);
        list.addNode(2);
        list.addNode(3);
        list.addNode(4);
        list.addNode(5);
        list.addNode(1);
        list.addNode(1);
        list.addNode(2);
        list.addNode(3);
        list.addNode(4);
        list.addNode(5);
        list.addNode(1);
        list.addNode(1);
        list.addNode(2);
        list.addNode(3);
        list.addNode(4);
        list.addNode(5);
        list.addNode(4);
        list.addNode(4);
        list.addNode(3);
        list.addNode(3);
        list.addNode(3);
        list.addNode(4);
        list.addNode(1);
        list.addNode(1);
        list.addNode(2);
        list.addNode(3);
        list.addNode(4);
        list.addNode(5);
        list.addNode(1);
        list.addNode(1);
        list.addNode(2);
        list.addNode(3);
        list.addNode(4);
        list.addNode(5);
        list.addNode(1);
        list.addNode(1);
        list.addNode(2);
        list.addNode(3);
        list.addNode(4);
        list.addNode(5);
        list.addNode(4);
        list.addNode(4);
        list.addNode(3);
        list.addNode(3);
        list.addNode(3);
        list.addNode(4);
        list.addNode(1);
        list.addNode(1);
        list.addNode(2);
        list.addNode(3);
        list.addNode(4);
        list.addNode(5);
        list.addNode(1);
        list.addNode(1);
        list.addNode(2);
        list.addNode(3);
        list.addNode(4);
        list.addNode(5);
        list.addNode(1);
        list.addNode(1);
        list.addNode(2);
        list.addNode(3);
        list.addNode(4);
        list.addNode(5);
        list.addNode(4);
        list.addNode(4);
        list.addNode(3);
        list.addNode(3);
        list.addNode(3);
        list.addNode(4);
        list.addNode(1);
        list.addNode(1);
        list.addNode(2);
        list.addNode(3);
        list.addNode(4);
        list.addNode(5);
        list.addNode(1);
        list.addNode(1);
        list.addNode(2);
        list.addNode(3);
        list.addNode(4);
        list.addNode(5);
        list.addNode(1);
        list.addNode(5);
        list.addNode(5);
        list.addNode(3);
        list.addNode(5);
        list.addNode(5);

        long start = System.nanoTime();

        System.out.println("List before sorting");
        list.printList(list.head);

        Node end = list.head;
        while (end.next != null) {
            end = end.next;
        }

        list.sort(list.head, end);

        System.out.println("\nList after sorting");
        list.printList(list.head);

        long ends = System.nanoTime();

        // execution time
        long execution = ends - start;
        execution /= 1000000;
        System.out.println("\nExecution time: " + execution + "milliseconds");

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With the following simplification to sort(), using start.data < pivot is a bit faster than start.data <= pivot, but you need to test with more data to see a difference.

```
    void sort(Node start, Node end) {
        if (start == null || start == end || start == end.next)
            return;
        Node pivot_prev = partition(start, end);

        sort(start, pivot_prev);

        sort(pivot_prev.next, end);
    }
```

This quicksort is a variation of Lomuto partition method, which degrades as the number of duplicates increases. One way to avoid this if sorting a single linked list is to use merge sort, but that rearranges nodes (their links) as opposed to swapping data.

---

addNode can be sped up by using a tail pointer:

```
    Node tail;
    // ...
    void addNode(int data) {
        Node newNode = new Node(data);
        if (head == null) {
            tail = head = newNode;
            return;
        }
        tail = tail.next = newNode;
    }
```